# ANNs traning, what happen in each epoche?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a question about the training of ANNs,

So I want to ask how the training is done for a set of input samples? Are there some relation between the size of the input set for training and the number of epoches for training, or it's totally independant?

For exemple, if my ANN has 4 inputs and for 2000 training's samples I get an input matrix of size 4x2000. So for *each epoche of training*, is that the whole matrix is loaded, or just one sample (training matrix column) is loaded for each epoche of traning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in each epoch of a NN all the weight values of the neurons are updated, all the nodes. Usually  the more neurons & layers & data you have the more epoches you need for a correct value for the weights, but there is not an equation for relationing epoches with neurons.

For the training usually there is used Backpropagation algorithm (check wikpedia for a great example), that updates each weight once. The more epoches the more accurate your NN will be. Usually for the training you set 2 variables: max num of epoches and accuracy, and when one of the two is finally achieved you stop iterating.

Comment: OK, thank you for responding,
But the question exactly was : "**for each epoche of training, is that the whole matrix is loaded, or just one sample (training matrix column) is loaded for each epoche of traning?**"

I have no clear answer yet,

Comment: Yes! the whole matrix. Every iteration is a whole calculus of the NN, so hypothetically it may happen that in the first epoch you get the perfect values! Every epoch recalculates the weight of the neurones trying to minimize the error comparing the previous epoch of the NN (if you want more info of how -> Backpropagation!). So yes! your matrix of 4x2000 has no info of epoches or nothing so it will take the whole set every iteration, calculate the weigths, simulate the NN and check if the output of the NN for your given data is equal to your given data

Comment: Just adding a little bit of extra information: This learning method is called batch learning, where the whole data set is used on each pass. You can also do mini-batch learning, where you use a subset of the data for each pass. This will cause the weights to converge in a zig-zagging fashion instead of a straight line, but it will run a lot faster. It's good for if you have millions of training examples and don't want to compute them all for every epoch. You can also do on-line learning, which uses one training example for each pass, this is more erratic, but even faster.

Comment: Thanks J.Ashworth, but how can I do it in Matlab ?

Comment: **trains** for mini-batch training and **trainc** or **trainoss** for online training.